# Spring Boot: Unit test with MockMVC throws a 404 when I add a Authorization header

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security, spring-test

I have what might be a very stupid issue / question. Firstly I'm fairly new to Unit testing in Spring

I have a API service which makes a "booking" / "reservation" on a third party API I'm trying to integrate with. My API is protected by Spring security and just ensure's a valid JWT has been passed in order to hit my endpoints.

I'm trying to create a test whereby when a user passes an invalid token the response is correctly a 401. Now I started off with the following:

```java
mockMvc.perform(post("/booking")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("Authorization", "eyJraWQiOiJDQnk5TFlvM2JUK0M2eVpvcWp3ZzEwTndXXC9GQWxjUURteHVHYWNZdDBhRT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9...")
        .content(objectToJson(request)))
    .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
```

For which I did indeed get a 401, however I realised I forgot to add bearer to the Authorization value. Once I added the bearer it now throws a 404.

```java
 mockMvc.perform
                        (post("/booking")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer eyJraWQiOiJDQnk5TFlvM2JUK0M2eVpvcWp3ZzEwTndXXC9GQWxjUURteHVHYWNZdDBhRT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.....")
                                .content(objectToJson(request))
                        )
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing incorrectly please?

here is the full code:

**Controller**

```
  @Operation(summary = "Booking Creation")
    @PostMapping("")
    public Mono<BookingResponse> userBooking(@RequestBody @Valid BookingCreateRequestDTO bookingCreateRequestDTO,
                                             @Parameter(hidden = true) Authentication authentication) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return bookingService.processBookingRequest(bookingCreateRequestDTO);
    }
```

here is my service layer:

```java
public Mono<BookingResponse> processBookingRequest(BookingCreateRequestDTO bookingCreateRequestDTO) throws JsonProcessingException {
        logger.info("Request Processing of Booking Request from client {}", bookingCreateRequestDTO.clientId);
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(xxxx)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .filter(ExchangeFilterFunctions.basicAuthentication(userName, userPwd))
                .build();
        //casting our bookingCreateRequestDTO object to a JSON payload
        String jsonBody = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bookingCreateRequestDTO);

        return webClient.post()
                .uri(URL)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(jsonBody))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(BookingResponse.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
                .doOnSuccess(response -> {
                    //Build email template objects
                });
    }
```

And finally here is my unit test

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@SpringJUnitConfig
@ContextConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SecurityConfig.class, BookingControllerTest.TestConfig.class})
class BookingControllerTest {

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Bean
        public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
            return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
        }

        // Other MVC configuration methods...
    }

    @Mock
    private BookingService bookingService;

    @InjectMocks
    private BookingController bookingController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(context)
                .setControllerAdvice(new GeneralBookingException()) // Add error handling advice
                .setControllerAdvice(new UnauthorizedException()) // Add error handling advice
                .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
                .build();
    }


    @Test
    public void testUserBooking_Unauthorized() throws Exception {
        // Prepare test data
        BookingCreateRequestDTO request = new BookingCreateRequestDTO();
        request.setClientId("client1");

        // Configure the bookingService to throw an exception (Unauthorized)
        given(bookingService.processBookingRequest(request))
                .willThrow(new UnauthorizedException("Unauthorized"));

        // Perform the API call
        mockMvc.perform
                        (post("/booking")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer eyJraWQiOiJDQnk5TFlvM2JUK0M2eVpvcWp3ZzEwTndXXC9GQWxjUURteHVHYWNZdDBhRT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.....")
                                .content(objectToJson(request))
                        )
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    // Helper method to convert object to JSON string
    private String objectToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }
}
```

Additional Notes here is my build file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id("org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin") version "1.6.0"
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.3.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '6.1.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '8.0.0.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui', version: '2.1.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api', version: '2.1.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui', version: '2.1.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api', version: '2.1.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-common', version: '2.1.0'

    implementation group: 'jakarta.validation', name: 'jakarta.validation-api', version: '3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'com.sendgrid', name: 'sendgrid-java', version: '4.9.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '32.1.1-jre'


    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '6.0.11'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '6.1.0'

    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test', Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "started", "skipped", "passed", "failed"
        showStandardStreams true
    }
```

Lastly here is my spring security config file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    String jwkSetUri;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html",
                                "/swagger-resources/**",
                                "/api-docs/swagger-config",
                                "/api-docs/*",
                                "/swagger-ui/*",
                                "/my/docs",
                                "/error",
                                "/favicon.ico",
                                "/*/*.png",
                                "/*/*.gif",
                                "/*/*.svg",
                                "/*/*.jpg",
                                "/*/*.html",
                                "/*/*.css").anonymous()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri).build();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot 3 security test with Mock JWT Authentication Token WithMockUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76792705/spring-boot-3-security-test-with-mock-jwt-authentication-token-withmockuser)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll give this ago and report back. It's a pity there's not a way to do this without using a third party lib

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use `MockMvc`, you can use `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()` which [I contributed to `spring-security-test`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/oauth2.html).

To use the annotations I wrote for OAuth2, you need [spring-addons-oauth2-test](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.c4-soft.springaddons/spring-addons-oauth2-test). Details on [my Github repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#2-unit--integration-testing-with-security).

I wrote an [article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control) covering the subject of testing Spring components and applications with mocked OAuth2 identities, but annotations have greatly improved recently and the article is not updated yet (editorial process at Baeldung can take some time). That said, the part of this article covering `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors` is still applicable.

Almost all I wrote as an answer to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76792705/spring-boot-3-security-test-with-mock-jwt-authentication-token-withmockuser) is applicable to you. Only one detail: @ScorprocS is using "my" Spring Boot starter (`spring-addons-starter-oidc`) in addition to `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, reason for using `spring-addons-starter-oidc-test` in my answer. If you're not using `spring-addons-starter-oidc`, `spring-addons-oauth2-test` (which contains just test annotations) is enough.